# Combining Two 3D Rotations

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations

Every rotation in 3D space can be defined by a rotation axis and an angle.
Now let's say we have two rotations $R_1 (\text{(axis)}_1, \text{(angle)}_1)$, $R_2 (\text{(axis)}_2, \text{(angle)}_2)$.

I remember that Rotation operator is closed under composition, so $R_1 (R_2(\text{object}))$ will be a rotation again.

Does anybody know how to find the new axis and angle for $R_1R_2$?

Comment: depending on what on context of the problem, you might compute the eigenspace of eigenvalue 1 (i.e. the rotation axis whose vectors are fixed under that rotation).

Comment: nice point of view :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once again, the easiest way of doing this (IMHO, at least) turns out to be quaternions: a rotation of $\theta$ about the (normalized) vector $\hat{v} = (v_0, v_1, v_2)$ is represented by the quaternion ${\bf q}=\mathrm{cos}(\theta/2) + \mathrm{sin}(\theta/2)*(v_0{\bf i}+v_1{\bf j}+v_2{\bf k})$; and quaternion multiplication is easy to compute. All you need are the base axioms ${\bf i}^2 = {\bf j}^2 = {\bf k}^2 = {\bf i}{\bf j}{\bf k} = -1$;  note that the latter implies for instance that ${\bf i}{\bf j} = {\bf k}$ by simply multiplying both sides on the right by ${\bf k}$ — on the right, because multiplication of quaternions, like composition of rotations, isn't commutative: $\bf{i}\bf{j}=\bf{k}$ but $\bf{j}\bf{i}=-\bf{k}$!. Once you have your resultant quaternion, the axis can be extracted as the (normalized) imaginary part of the result and the angle can be found by taking the arc-cosine of the scalar part.  See the Wikipedia page on [quaternions and rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) for more details on just how this works.

Comment: Why once again?

Comment: This just feels like the third or fourth question in the last few days where my answer has been 'quaternions'.  They're a favorite topic of mine, mind, so I certainly don't mind another chance to extol their virtues!

Comment: Thanks, elegant and neat! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link to  Wikipedia . Although I knew the mathematics of that page beforehand,  I am awed by its quality and the effectiveness  of the illustrations (not to mention their sheer beauty). And I agree with you 100% on the virtues of quaternions: they are definitely the best tool for composing rotations. So, +1.

Comment: This answer misses the result, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/3drota.htm

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to use of quaternion math:

[This method requires ability to do a generalized coordinate rotation in 3D computationally].

There is a fairly simple way to convert from [ Euler axis, Euler angle ] representation into a 3x3 rotator matrix.  Once the two rotators are in matrix form, you just bang them together into the composite transform R1 • R2.

To convert [ Euler axis, euler angle ] to 3x3 matrix:

1. Transform the standard x-axis direction [ 1  0  0 ] using the Euler spec.

   a. First put direction [ 1 0 0 ] into rotated coordinates where the newZaxis takes on the value of the Euler axis direction.

   b. Call a rotation of the Euler angle amount about the z-axis on the results from a.

   c. Call the inverse rotation transform used in a. on the results from b.

You now have a direction vector giving the value of newXaxis (first column of your 3x3 rotator).

Repeat the same transform process on the other standard axes:

process  [ 0  1  0 ] to obtain the newYaxis

process  [  0  0  1 ] to obtain the newZaxis

Finally compose your equivalent 3x3 rotator matrix R

R =  [  newXaxis   newYaxis  newZaxis  ]

and use matrix composition to combine any 2 two such rotators.

The final part of your questions appeals to how to convert a 3x3 rotator matrix into [ Euler axis, Euler angle ] representation.

I've found this approach to work well (using software):

1. Find the midplane of 3D space between direction vectors [ 1 0 0 ] and newXaxis.
2. Find the midplane of 3D space between direction vectors [ 0 1 0 ] and newYaxis.
3. The intersection of the two midplanes (a 3D line) gives the Euler axis direction.
4. Construct a plane thru the origin orthogonal to the Euler axis.  Project any of the "before-after" pairs onto direction vectors on this plane, e.g. [ 1 0 0 ] and newXaxis.  The cos(Euler angle) is the dot product of these 2 projected direction vectors.  The sin(Euler angle) is the magnitude of their cross product.  You can use an IEEE "atan2(sin, cos)" function to obtain an accurate measure of the Euler angle.

If algorithmizing this conversion, be sure to pick off the edge cases before plowing forward into the midplane calcs.  These cases are the identity rotator, and the 3 single axis rotators (e.g., rotate about x-axis, about negative x-axis, 
y-axis, negative y-axis, etc.)